# If Statement assistance

Tags: powershell

The If statement below keeps advising i have a missing statement block after if. Can anyone point me in the right direction on sorting the IF statement?

```
If ($ts = (Get-Date) - (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime)
```

I know its the IF statementbut cannot work out why? Full CODE below...

```
#subtract the LastBootUpTime date from the current date and time to get a TimeSpan object

If ($ts = (Get-Date) - (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#write-Host "Exit Error Message"

{

Exit 1001


} else {

#now format it into a human readable string to go in the report

$UpTime = '{0} days {1} hours {2} minutes {3} seconds' -f $ts.Days, $ts.Hours, $ts.Minutes, 
$ts.Seconds

write-host "The Up-Time is:" $UpTime

#write-host "Exit Success Message"

Exit 0

}
```

Comment: Try removing the commented out statement between the if and the opening `{`. Or move it to within the block statement.

Comment: In your first code snippet, you are missing the closing `)`. In the next code snippet, you added `-ErrorAction` but it doesn’t belong to any command because you have enclosed all your commands in `()` and didn’t include the parameter

Comment: You need to use a [comparison operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) (e.g. `-eq`) *not* an assignment operator (`=`)

Comment: @AdminOfThings If I use ($ts = (Get-Date) - (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) it advises a error  on the -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Comment: Because the `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` needs to be on the Cim command, not after the dot notated property. `($ts = (Get-Date) - (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).LastBootUpTime) `

Comment: Thanks @DougMaurer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your logic is flawed. What you're attempting to do is called variable squeezing which means if $ts gets populated, do something; else do something different. So if your command succeeds and populates $ts you are trying to exit with code 1001, which seems opposite of what you desire.

Next, you need to finish your if parenthesis block `( )` and move the erroraction parameter to its correct location on the command. Until you're more familiar with how to structure the statement it may be much easier to separate the statements.

```
#subtract the LastBootUpTime date from the current date and time to get a TimeSpan object
$ts = (Get-Date) - (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).LastBootUpTime

If ($ts)
{
    #now format it into a human readable string to go in the report

    $UpTime = '{0} days {1} hours {2} minutes {3} seconds' -f $ts.Days, $ts.Hours, $ts.Minutes, $ts.Seconds

    write-host "The Up-Time is:" $UpTime

    #write-host "Exit Success Message"

    exit 0
}
else
{
    #write-Host "Exit Error Message"

    exit 1001
}
```

or broken down even further like this

```
#subtract the LastBootUpTime date from the current date and time to get a TimeSpan object
$lastboot = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).LastBootUpTime
$ts = (Get-Date) - $lastboot

If ($ts)
{
    #now format it into a human readable string to go in the report

    $UpTime = '{0} days {1} hours {2} minutes {3} seconds' -f $ts.Days, $ts.Hours, $ts.Minutes, $ts.Seconds

    write-host "The Up-Time is:" $UpTime

    #write-host "Exit Success Message"

    exit 0
}
else
{
    #write-Host "Exit Error Message"

    exit 1001
}
```

Comment: Thanks @DougMaurer for your assistance in the problem.